# Variables in methods

Tags: java, variables

I have a program to test if a certain place in a board game is occupied by black (versus red). I have `private static int _row = 0, _col = 0` in my program, outside of my methods. In my isBlack method, I try to change the value of the two fields by doing, for example, _row = (some value). However, in other methods, even after I call isBlack, the fields remain the same! (They are not set to the new value.) Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show us the code which you are talking about?

Comment: 1. Please post some code.  2. dont name variables like _row, _col. use camelCase.

Comment: `Am I missing something?` - some code to show us.

Comment: Voted to close as OP did not provide further details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has something to do with your variables being declared `static`. Unless the `isBlack` method is `static`, these variables (judging by what they do) should not be `static`. `static` means that there is only one copy of the member, and that in any instance that you create containing a `static` member, it will still remain the same, even in different instances.

I cannot know for sure though, as you have no code to show. But my best guess is that this is why your problem is occuring.